# Relationship between nullspace and column space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

As column space is Combination of solution for $Ax=b$

And nullspace is Combination of solution for $Ax=0$

Does this mean that nullspace is a subspace of column space?

Comment: The column space is all such $\mathbf{b}$ such that $Ax = b$ can be solved, while the null space is the space of all such $\mathbf{x}$ such that $Ax = 0$ can be solved. In particular, if $A$ is not a square matrix, the column space and null space belong to different spaces, so there is no question of one being a subspace of the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the expression $Ax=b$ the columns of $A$ are combinated by the vector $x$ to obtain $b$ thus $b$ needs to belong to the column space of $A$ but $x$ in general is not related to column space of $A$.

Let consider for example to an $A_{n\times m}$ matrix, in this case $b\in R^n$ but $x\in R^m$.